# Como ler determinada linha de vários arquivos em Java

Tags: java, array, sistema-de-arquivos

Na pasta Estoque, tenho vários arquivos.txt. Gostaria de ler cada linha desse arquivos. A pergunta é: como?

OBS: se eu conseguisse salvar o nome de cada arquivo, eu talvez conseguiria resolver o problema. Mas não consigo usar o getName();

Tentei desenvolver, mas não deu certo.

```java
String path = "../Aplicação Bodega/src/br/com/Estoque/";
public Produto[] produtosEmFalta() {

        Produto produto[] = null;
        Produto produtoaux = null;
        int a = 0;

        File arquivo[];
        File diretorio = new File(path);
        arquivo = diretorio.listFiles();


        for(int i = 0; i < diretorio.length(); i++){
           try{
                List linhas = new ArrayList<>();
                Scanner leitor = new Scanner(arquivo[i]);

                //System.out.println(arquivo[0]);


                while(leitor.hasNextLine()){
                    linhas.add(leitor.nextLine()); 
                }

                produtoaux = buscar((String)linhas.get(i));


                if(produtoaux.getQuantidade() == 0){
                    System.out.println("Código: " + produtoaux.getCodigo());
                    //produto[a] = produtoaux;
                    a++;
                }

           } catch(FileNotFoundException | PNEException ex) { }
        }

        return produto;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

O seu 'for' está errado. Você está usando 'diretorio.length()' na condição do loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < diretorio.length(); i++){
```

mas deveria estar considerando o valor 'arquivo.length', afinal, é neste array que estão os arquivos do diretório referenciado na variável 'diretorio'

```
 for(int i = 0; i < arquivo.length; i++){
```

com isso você consegue acessar o nome de cada arquivo dentro do loop:

```
arquivo[i].getName()
```